# CalDAV Client for Windows/Linux/OSX/Android

Tags: http, calendar, webdav, caldav, carddav

Is anybody aware of any CalDAV client for Windows/Linux/OSX/Android that implements MKCALENDAR request and reports defined in RFC4791 (CALDAV:calendar-query, CALDAV:free-busy-query etc.)?

I've tested a few clients, but they use CalDAV server as a simple WebDAV storage and doesn't allow to perform advanced requests.

Comment: BTW, maybe you know some fully functional CardDAV client too?

Comment: How is that a programming question?

Answer (score 1):

Might have been useful to mention which clients you did try but the default iCalendar client on Mac OS certainly does make use of MKCALENDAR (or extended MKCOL) as it allows creation of new calendars.

The iOS default calendar client does make use of time-range calendar query.

Answer (score 0):

CalDAV-Sync on Android uses `calendar-query` if no support for the more efficient `sync-collection` report is available on a server.